# Как скомпилировать Qt для Arm под g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator, arm

Установил компилятор для работы с Arm (**g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf**, и **gcc-multilib, g++-multilib**  для кроссплатформенной компиляции), настроил Kit'ы для работы с этим компилятором и подключенным устройством - все нормально работает с std c++11. Теперь хочу чтобы c Qt заработало. Мой план такой - скомпилировать Qt, подключить эту версию к существующему Киту, подключить Qt статически к своему проекту и выполнять целевую бинарку на Arm'е.

Буду благодарен за любые ваши указания советы, которые хочу почитать перед началом конфигурации/компиляции/инсталяции, чтобы не наступать на те же грабли.

- Qt хочу скомпилировать 5.7
- OS хоста Ubuntu 15.10 64bit
- Qt Creator 3.6.0
- на Arm стоит 32 бита Debian GNU/Linux 7

**Важно**, что никакую графику на Арме выполнять не нужно, по-моему это должно облегчить задачу. Тип проекта будет Qt based console C++

---

Хороша ли, например, такая кофигурация:

> ./configure -prefix /home/[myname]/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-5.7 -debug
>   -static -qt-zlib -qt-sql-sqlite2 -no-qml-debug -no-widgets -no-gui -no-opengl -openssl-linked -opensource -confirm-license -silent

? Что еще добавить/убавить? **-embedded** флаг в пятом вроде уже не действует (?)

**На каком этапе** нужно будет указать компилятор **g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf**? На этапе конфигурации или поздней?

---

Отредактированно: что вписать для опции **-platform**?

---

Итак был вопрос, что вписать для флага **platform**. Оказалось, что все "платформы" лежат в **qtbase/mkspecs**. Теперь яснен ответ на вопрос "где указать компилятор. Нашел там платформу **близкую** к нужной мне: **linux-arm-gnueabi-g++**. Это тоже что и **linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++**, но без поддрержки плавающих точек. Пошел на хак - скопировал **linux-arm-gnueabi-g++** в **linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++** и прописал в qmake.conf нужный мне (установленный у меня) компилятор:

```
# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy
QMAKE_NM                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm -P
QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
```

Конфиг сработал, но тут новая бяда:

```
Creating qmake...
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Running configuration tests...
Failed to process makespec for platform 'linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++'
... Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

---

Из любопытства установил **g++-arm-linux-gnueabi** и выполнил с "легальной" платформой:

```
-platform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
```

высыпало:

```
Creating qmake...
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: error: project.o uses VFP register arguments, ../bin/qmake does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file project.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: error: option.o uses VFP register arguments, ../bin/qmake does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file option.o
```

(об этом я говорил выше - g++-arm-linux-gnueabi не поддерживает плавающие точки, но даже "легальная" версия просто так не устанавливается

Кстати, нашел [рекомендации](https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/Middleware/Graphics/Qt/CrossCompiling) примерно того, что делал я, но на практике не срабатывает из-за `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`. Попробую покомбинировать флаги

---

**И вот на этой ошибке я и застрял.** `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Текущая конфигурация, которую пытаюсь запустить:

> ./configure -prefix /home/rishat/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-5.7 -debug
>   -platform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-sql-sqlite2 -no-qml-debug -no-widgets -no-gui -no-opengl -openssl-linked -opensource -confirm-license -v

Comment: Например: radix.pro, buildroot etc. Из вашего вопроса не очень понятно, какие "причендалы для кроссплатформенной компиляции" у вас есть. А с помощью вышеназванных систем можно занматься кросскомпляцией под разные платформы.

Comment: @user1056837 gcc-multilib g++-multilib установил и все заработало. Сейчас проблема правильно Qt построить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-platform` - хостовая архтектура

`-xplatform` - целевая

Ну и если бы вы хоть немного посмотрели в англоязычном сегменте, то увидели бы порядочное количество схожих вопросов с ответами.

Comment: Да, с -xplatform пошло, правда не хватает некоторых библиотек, но, думаю, разберусь. Буду надеяться на арме пойдет

Comment: Пожалуйста послушайте совет и воспользуйтесь средствами для кросскомпиляции. Это гораздо более надёжный подход.

Comment: После ряда шаманств выдала QTBUG-36129 (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36129) Наверно придется попробовать ваши инструменты (или же делать проект на std+boost). Спасибо за советы! Оставляю этот вопрос закрытым и задам отдельный вопрос по этому багу, может кто знает воркэраунд

Answer (score 1):

Достиг успеха следующей конфигурацией:

> ./configure -prefix /home/asianirish/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-openssl-5.7
>   -debug -static -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtsensors -skip qttools -skip qtwebsockets -skip
>   qtwinextras -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -nomake examples
>   -qt-zlib -c++std c++11 -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-sql-psql -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-oci -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-db2 -no-opengl -sysroot /home/asianirish/olimex/ -opensource -confirm-license -v

Включил флаг `-sysroot` для доступности некоторых библиотек.

Все компилируется с Qt и выполняется на Арме. Огромное спасибо @user1056837 за ценный совет. Оставляю свой ответ на случай если кому пригодится в аналогичной ситуации.